# updating content,changing url without loading the page window.history.pushState

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Hello all i am planning to use window.history.pushState in my site but i have little knowledge how to do this..

what i want is that i have a page **dashboard.php** and want to update the url to **dashboard.php?do=edit&who=me** and load the div with id **contentdiv** do not load the whole page....

i know this can be done by this code

```
 function processAjaxData(response, urlPath){
   document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = response.html;
   document.title = response.pageTitle;
   window.history.pushState({
     "html":response.html,
     "pageTitle":response.pageTitle}, "", urlPath);
 }

  window.onpopstate = function(e){
    if(e.state){
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = e.state.html;
      document.title = e.state.pageTitle;
    }
};
```

but i don't know how to implement this what to put in response of the function.

and also i want if the browser do not support this then in that case this should act like a link and refreshing the page may be ok

any idea / help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Use some JavaScript routing library, for example **Routie** which you can find on GitHub - http://projects.jga.me/routie/

Example of routing with Routing and jQuery used you got below:

```
routie({
    'dashboard/edit/:who': function (who) {
       $.ajax({
           url: 'api.php',
           data: {prop: 'propVal'},
           method: 'POST'
       })
       .done(function (res) {
          console.log(res);
       });
    }
);
```

To run a function above, get in `YOURSITE.COM#dashboard/edit/me` instead of `YOURSITE.COM/dashboard.php?=...`.